# How can we check the output of BashOperator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm very new to Airflow, I wonder if I execute a bash operator, how can we get the console output of that Operator? I'm wondering does setting `xcom_push = true` solve the problem?
I'd very glad of anyone can answer this :)

Answer (score 2):

For those using Airflow 2+, BashOperator now returns the entire output ([source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/bash.py)), not just the last line and does not require specifying `do_xcom_push` (new name in 2+ instead of `xcom_push`), as it is true by default.

Comment: This is not true at all.  If you look at the doc string for the operator in the source you linked, it says *"If BaseOperator.do_xcom_push is True, the **last line** written to stdout
    will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes"*.  In addition, if you dig further into the code and look at the `SubprocessHook` that is called as part of `BashOperator.execute()`, it shows that only the last line is output is returned.  Instead, I recommend using @parakeet's solution below of piping the command output to the `tr` command.

Answer (score 1):

If `xcom_push` is `True`, only the **last line** written to stdout will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes.

Related source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.11/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L167-L168

Answer (score 1):

To add to @kaxil's answer (as I don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer):

If your `bash_command` returns multiple lines that you want to include in xcom then add this to return everything on one line:

```
bash_command="<COMMAND> | tr '\n' '||'",
```